# How to get the info of the file which is currently being requested by the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, load

There happens a HTTP request for each css, image and js file being loaded, can I somehow get the name, size of the file being requested.

Currently Loading: 
style.css - 50% .. 60% .. 100%
                   jquery.min.js  - 50% .. 60% .. 100%

Comment: i think you can only get them after they load

Comment: I saw this happening on a website a while ago, can't remember its name or address. It was displaying the file being loaded in a fixed positioned div at the bottom left of the window.

Comment: that's different. if the webpage is already loaded, then you can use ajax to fetch such resources, and ajax provides a progress event to track. you can't, during loading, get info about everything that's been requested until it loads, then you can use `performance.getEntries()` to review them. note that you may be able to at least tell what's remaining by scanning the markup (html/css) for URLs and comparing that to getEntries()'s known assets.